# Mongodb one-to-many get number of children

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections:

```js
Users: [{
  _id: 'xxx',
  name: 'xxx',
},
...
]

Posts: [{
  _id: 'xxx',
  userId: 'xxx',
},
...
]
```

So a user can have multiple posts. I want to get users with the number of posts that each user has. If the user doesn't have any post, it should load `0`.

So the result will be:

```js
[{
  _id: 'xxx',
  name: 'xxx',
  numberOfPosts: 'xxx'
},
...
]
```

Below query is what I have wrote:

```js
$lookup: {
  from: 'Posts',
  let: {
    userId: '$_id',
  },
  pipeline: [{
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: ["$userId", "$$userId"]
      }
    }
  }, {
    $count: 'posts'
  }, {
    $project: {
      posts: {
        $cond: [{
          $ifNull: ['$posts', true]
        },
        '$posts',
        0
      ]},
    }
  }],
  as: 'posts'
}
```

It doesn't give me 0 if a user doesn't have any post. What was wrong in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try simple way,

- use `$lookup` without pipeline
- `$addFields` to count the number of posts using `$size`

```
db.Users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Posts",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "userId",
      as: "numberOfPosts"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      numberOfPosts: {
        $size: "$numberOfPosts"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VROBGsy1Iyr)